# Profile 2 display field on my account page

Tags: users

Use this module - Profile2 Registration Path and Profile2 -  when registering, so that would be made ​​at check-in person was filling certain fields, in this regard, I have a question - how do I display the fields that person fills during registration, on the profile page?

Comment: if my answer was useful do not forget mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un-check "Provide a separate page for editing profiles." on the edit profile page. The help text states:

> If enabled, a separate menu item for editing the profile is generated and the **profile is hidden from the user account page**.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable profile2 pages, that comes with the core of profile 2

That module will add different pages per profile types in the user account. so your users can select their profile and check for the fields they filled during registration

Comment: i use profile2 pages - and i have page in Secondary menu My account - but on this page i see only "Send this user a private message
History 
Member for
2 hours 8 min" this page www.mysite.com/user

Comment: if the page is empty is because 2 reasons. The user did not fill the fields during registration or because the profile does not have fields. If your users filled the profile fields during registration they must be able to see them in the profile page.